# What can I use to seal section of concrete roof?

Tags: roof, sealing, roofing, sealer, sealant

We have a rough concrete roof, and it's leaking in a particular section. In that particular section, there's very little pooling and there's some leaking. It's very sunny here, so the water ends up evaporating after a few hours.

The section to be painted is about 8x8ft, and the pooling's in the middle. I'm looking for a product that I can use to seal that section of the roof. There will still be some pooling but it won't leak. I'm not going to fix the roof; I will just paint it and hope for the best. Please don't suggest anything beyond that.

I went to the hardware store, and I found all these products. Unfortunately, nobody over there knew which I should use.

What's the difference between an `Ultra Siliconizer`, a `Fiber Reinforced Elastomeric Urethane Roof Sealer`, traditional or Siliconized `Acrylic Elastomeric Coating`, regular `Elastomeric sealer`? There are so many options, and it seems nobody at the store could tell me what I could use.

There's very little traffic in that section of the roof. The only thing it needs to withstand is the little pooling, just until it evaporates when the sun's up.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: For a specific product yes, but for a type of product that should be fine. If he was asking should I use Sherwin Williams or Pittsburgh that would be off topic, asking if an elastomeric or an epoxy would be better should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a two part epoxy similar to this:

[Mult-E-Poxy](https://www.diamondvogel.com/content/mult-e-poxy-180-epoxy-mastic)

This is a two part system and very durable. I have it on my garage floor.

To prep the surface you are going to want to clean the space with muratic acid (it's nasty stuff).  The acid cleans out the pores in the concrete and etches the surface to ensure good adhesion of the paint.

Once the acid does its thing (follow the directions on the bottle) rinse the surface with water to remove the acid and any crud it removes.

**Ensure you wait until the concrete is fully dry.**

Once dry (a full day in the sun is a safe bet unless you live somewhere super humid) apply the epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your building supply and look for Henry's Aluminum Roof Coating. It is what is used to coat and seal metal roofing. I have used this kind product to seal a mobile home roof and an old barn metal roof. Just make sure the concrete is dry and is free of dust and debris.  Buy a cheap stirring paddle you can connect to a drill to stir the product mixing it well. Depending on how rough the concrete you might have to use multiple coats.  You can use a paint roller and brushes.

Comment: Products designed for metal probably aren't best suited for concrete, not saying it wouldn't work but an exterior coating designed for concrete would likely be better.

Comment: Yes I understand but he ask for a simple low cost solution and that stuff will bond to just about anything. Plus he said the surface was rough and that will fill the spaces.